# An error I just don't get, MYSQL PDO PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Trying to run this insert query

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `contacts` (`id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `phonenumber`, `rank`, `time`) VALUES (NULL, :firstname, :lastname, :authcode, '1', NOW()");
$query->execute(array(":firstname" => $firstname, ":lastname" => $lastname, ":phone" => $phone));
$message[1] = '<font color=lime>Successfully added!</font>';
```

I get this error:

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 in /public_html/contacts/add.php on line 61

This `($query->execute(array...)` being line 61

Answer (score 3):

Your query is incorrect, that's why you are receiving syntax error. You missed ending `)`.

```
INSERT INTO contacts (
   id,
   firstname,
   lastname,
   phonenumber,
   rank,
   time
) VALUES (
   NULL,
   :firstname,
   :lastname,
   :phone,
   '1',
   NOW()
)
```

It's easier to find such mistakes after formatting query.

Comment: Thanks I literally got it after posting it out but thank you again for the good mind of helping.

Comment: you don`t even have :phone in your query, you have :authcode instead of phone

Comment: @geryjuhasz Nice, so there was another one mistake in that query.